# how to get average value from 2 colomn ini mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table = table_a
and filed =
val1,val2,val3 =(10,10,7)

i want get Avg value from val1,val2,val3 on mysql, i was try with AVG(val1,val2,val3) from table_a it's not work,

somebody can help me?

thanks

Comment: Pls post your query and elaborate what it means that it's not working? Do you get error, no results or incorrect results?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - although, on the face of it, this looks like poor design

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get the average of the columns not rows, just perform basic calculation

```
(val1 + val2 + val3) / 3.0 AS Average
```

Comment: you beat me with the speed :). removed my answer.